# Send private message in a public channel discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How do you create this
[image]
in `discord.js` version `12.5.3`. I mean that `Only you can see this`. I know how to send message to a channel using `message.channel.send` but how do I send the `Only you can see this` message. Thank you

Comment: According to https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/kqwgqe/i_saw_a_custom_bot_send_only_you_can_see_this/ they are related to https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/application-commands

Comment: but how do I send it after on message event

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way of sending these types of "hidden" messages on Discord.js **v12**, it is feature introduced on **v13** on Interactions. Which are related to slash commands and buttons.

Pretty sure you can not send them as it from `message` (or `messageCreate`) event.

You can read more about [Ephemeral responses](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/replying-to-slash-commands.html#ephemeral-responses) and maybe work on your implemention of slash commands to your bot

Comment: and can you tell me of a command for triggering the slash command

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but you can read this guide to find the way to implememt slash commands https://discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html#guild-commands

Comment: I mean I have a button and I want to trigger the slash command on click of the button